# C# - Listbox Remove part of line

Tags: c#, listbox, replace, split

I have a listbox that has contents that look like this:

```
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0    0603_5    
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0    0603_5    
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90   0402_2    
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0    0402_4    
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  90   0402_3     
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90   0402_3    
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0    0402_4    
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90   TANT3216  
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0    0402_9
```

On the click of a button, I would like to **"REMOVE ENDINGS"** and re-upload it to the ListBox.
So the new ListBox would look like this:

```
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0 
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  90
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0
```

All of the possibly endings are in this REGEX:
`Regex placementOneRegex = new Regex(@"(RES|0402|0201|0603|0805|1206|1306|1608|3216|2551|1913|1313|2513|5125|2525|5619|3813|1508|6431|2512|1505|2208|1005|1010|2010|0505|0705|1020|1812|2225|5764|4532|1210|0816|0363|SOT)");`

***CODE:***

```
    private void removeEndingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] items;
        System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection contents = placementOneListBox.Items;

        foreach (string str in contents)
        {
            Regex placementOneRegex = new Regex(@"(RES|0402|0201|0603|0805|1206|1306|1608|3216|2551"
                + @"|1913|1313|2513|5125|2525|5619|3813|1508|6431|2512|1505|2208|1005|1010|2010|0505|0705"
                + @"|1020|1812|2225|5764|4532|1210|0816|0363|SOT)");
            items = str.Split(' ');
            items[5].Replace(placementOneRegex.ToString(), "");
            placementOneListBox.Items.Equals(items);
        }
```

As you can probably tell.. this is not the best away to go about it.  I think it would be easiest to `string.Split()` and then just *join* all the `split`'s except the `split[5]`... except I do not know how to go about doing this..

- My code does not work

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- How do I grab each line in the listbox and remove the last piece of data *(using `string.Split()`)*?
- Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: If what you have works...Why are you trying to change it.  You could create a string array of what to match I just don't see the point.  What you have now is the easier way instead of having to remember to update an array of strings every single time and ending is added.  I also have no idea what your talking about the split[5] being a problem.   How you post an attempt at doing it and we simply go from there.

Comment: Does the data reload into the same listbox after removing the ending? If so, why display with the ending in the first place? Why not trim the excess first?

Comment: @Ramhound: It doesn't work :-/.. and the split[5] is the place where the **endings** are at so I was attempting to replace the split[5] with nothing.. that didn't work in my code above..

Comment: @IAbstract: Yeah that data will load into the same listbox. The reason why the endings are displayed is because I need to view the endings to make sure that they are in the proper places and that everything was loaded properly as well as other issues. Then I have to trim the endings so I can properly save the listbox items and load the file in another location.

Comment: *another location = a different program that I am running that needs a special format

Comment: Am I right in assuming the apparent fixed column format in your example list is an accident? Otherwise it looks like you could just SubString the first 43 characters.

Comment: @seveland: Unforunately there is not a fixed column width. Each column is seperated with a space/tab and each column can be any length really..

Comment: *...is because I need to view the endings to make sure that they are in the proper places and that everything was loaded properly* - this is usually done in a logging scenario. I advise against loading a UI control simply for the sake of doing so. Use a RichTextBox and log loading results there ...???

Comment: @IAbstract: I am using a ListBox because it is easiest for the user to use. I have buttons that allow the user to move items up and down to order the items in the list, as well as "adding" and "removing" from the ListBox. Also moving items from one ListBox to another ListBox. This is why I am using a ListBox.. everything can be done with a click of a button on the screen. If I used a RichTextBox it would be more difficult to move items from one to another by a click of a button.. as well as adding and removing.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?  I didn't test it.

```
private void removeEndingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] items;
    System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection contents = placementOneListBox.Items;

    foreach (string str in contents)
    {

       List<string> list = str.Split(' ').ToList();
       if(list.Count == 6)
       {
           string remove = list[5];
           list.Remove(remove);           
           placementOneListBox.Items.Equals(list.ToArray());
       }
    }
}
```

if those are tabs you might want to try  '\t' in the split method.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, when I scroll over the red line under `str.Split(' ').ToList().Remove(remove);`, it states **"Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'"**

Comment: When I click on the `removeEndingsButton` and error pops up stating **"Index was outside the bounds of the array."** pointing at the line `string remove = str.Split(' ')[5];`

Comment: updated again.  I assumed that ' ' was the correct character to split and that there would always be 6 items after the split.  You might have to tweek it a little to get it to  work, but you should have the basic idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void removeEndingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] items;
        char[] splitChars = new char[] {'\t', ' '};
        int fieldCount;
        int lineCount = 0;

        System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection contents = placementOneListBox.Items;

        foreach (string str in contents)
        {
           lineCount++;
           items = str.Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           fieldCount = items.Length;
           placementOneListBox.Items[lineCount] = string.Join(" ", items.Take(fieldCount - 1).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only part I'm not 100% on is the use of placementOneListBox.Items.Equals; the split and re-concatenation works.

Comment: There is an error when the button is clicked stating, **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** and pointing to `placementOneListBox.Items.Equals(string.Concat(items[0], " ", items[1], " ", items[2], " ", items[3]));`

Comment: Is there a constraint on the number of fields each line can possibly contain? Or is it simply >= 0?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking, but I think it is simply >= 0

Comment: Sorry for the flurry of incomplete edits - having connectivity issues at the moment :).

Comment: haha happens to the best of us :). With the current code you posted nothing happens when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data I'm thinking that you could use a string position to remove the endings.  It looks like you want to truncate each entry after the 33rd position.

Are all the lines in this format?

Comment: The values will not always end in the same spot

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but it does what you are looking for essentially. You have to tweak the Join to make it output how you want.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox.ObjectCollection collection = placementOneListBox.Items;
        // New collection to store our modified data
        List<string> newCollection = new List<string>();
        // We need regex to account for 0 or more spaces between items in the array.
        Regex r = new Regex(" +");

        foreach (string item in collection)
        {
            // use the regex we created to split the item into an array, it splits it based on any number of spaces.
            string[] splitItem = r.Split(item);
            // We had to write an extension method that "removes" at a particular index.
            splitItem = splitItem.RemoveAt(5);
            // Put it back together again. might have to mess with this to make it output correctly
            string updatedItem = String.Join("    ", splitItem);
            // add new item to collection
            newCollection.Add(updatedItem);
        }
        // clear the existing stuff in the listbox collection
        placementOneListBox.Items.Clear();
        // we can use a List<T> as a data source so that's what were doing here.
        placementOneListBox.DataSource = newCollection;
    }


}
```

EDIT: Put this code in it's own class as is.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    // An extension method to remove an index from an array, it works with any value type
    public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] source, int index)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (index < 0 || index > source.Length)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        T[] dest = new T[source.Length - 1];

        if (index != 0)
            Array.Copy(source, 0, dest, 0, index - 1);

        if (index != source.Length)
            Array.Copy(source, index + 1, dest, index, source.Length - index - 1);

        return dest;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Don't use my previous one, I had to fix the extension method, it wasn't working when the specified index to be removed was 0 or the length of the array.

Comment: The `splitItem.**RemoveAt(5)**` does not seem to be working. Do you know what is wrong wit hit?

Comment: What isnt working about it? What error are you getting specifically.

Comment: The error I am getting is: `('System.Array' does not contain a defnition 'RemoveAt' and no extension method 'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I edited my post. Make sure you aren't dropping the method into the form class. Make sure it is in its own static class like shown in my edit.

Comment: I changed it so it is in its own class. Ooops. haha. However, now the exception in the static class is throwing: **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Comment: Did you copy my latest code? You shouldn't have that error unless you are passing it an index to remove that is greater than the total count of items in the array.

Comment: I copied your latest code to make sure.. still threw the same error... hmmm