# C# - Order a ListBox by its' strings & Remove a piece of the string

Tags: c#, string, listbox, replace

I have a file that I am uploading to a RichTextBox and then displaying it to a ListBox after I have formatted it.  The ListBox looks like this *(minus some lines that I deleted so it is shorter to work with)*:

```
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0    0603_5
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0    0603_5
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90   0402_2
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0    0402_4
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  180  0402_3
Q7      IC-00268G   258.460  205.594  0    SOT236
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90   0402_3
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0    0402_4
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90   TANT3216
R21     CAP-00129G -123.370 -112.114  270  0402_3
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0    0402_9
...     ..........  .......  .......  ...  ........
```

Anyways, I would like to sort the ListBox by the ending on the strings... so the values in the **6th** column (0603_5, 0603_5, 0402_2, 0402_4, 0402_3, TANT3216, 0402_9....). By doing this it would cause the new ListBox to be ordered in this order *(although not all of these are shown in the file example)*:

**`RES, 0402, 0201, 0603, 0805, 1206, 1306, 1608, 3216, 2551, 1913, 1313, 2513, 5125, 2525, 5619, 3813, 1508, 6431, 2512, 1505, 2208, 1005, 1010, 2010, 0505, 0705, 1020, 1812, 2225, 5764, 4532, 1210, 0816, 0363, SOT.`**

(notice the `TANT3216` comes before `SOT236` because it is going off of the number *3216* not *TANT* in the above ordering list)

Also, if there are multiple endings that are similar (see *0402_3* above and below), then the list item will be sorted by the **2nd** column. So even though the line beginning with `R21` comes after the line beginning with `C25`, and they both end with *0402_3*, `R21` will be placed above `C25`  because it the 2nd column is checked after the 6th column (this is sorted from smallest to largest).

**SO,** the new file would look like this:

```
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90   0402_2
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  180  0402_3
R21     CAP-00129G -123.370 -112.114  270  0402_3
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90   0402_3
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0    0402_4
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0    0402_4
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0    0402_9
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0    0603_5
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0    0603_5
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90   TANT3216
Q7      IC-00268G   258.460  205.594  0    SOT236
...     ..........  .......  .......  ...  ........
```

Once the ListBox is sorted I have a button **(that is not working properly)** to replace the end value of each the string line in the ListBox with a `" "`. **So,** on the click of a button, I would like to **"REMOVE ENDINGS"** and re-upload it to the same ListBox.
So the same *(updated)* ListBox would look like this:

```
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  180
R21     CAP-00129G -123.370 -112.114  270
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90
Q7      IC-00268G   258.460  205.594  0
...     ..........  .......  .......  ...
```

***NOT WORKING (CODE):***

```
private void removePackageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection contents = placementOneListBox.Items;   
    foreach (string str in contents)
    {
        List<string> list = str.Split(' ').ToList();
        if (list.Count == 6)
        {
            string remove = list[5];
            list.Remove(remove);

            placementOneListBox.Items.Equals(list.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- I have no idea on how to go about this and I am looking for any help possible.
- Is there another way to go about this that is much simpler?

Comment: You should think about storing this data into some data structure rather than trying to manipulate the string representation of the data all the time. Once you define a data structure you can do all sorts of things like sorting very easily.

Comment: `placementOneListBox.Items.Equals(..)` is not what you want - you can add or remove items to the listbox using `.Items.Add(..)` /  `.Items.Remove(..)`

Comment: @Odnxe: I am very unfamiliar with C# and have been trying to learn it.. lol. How could I go about doing that?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I tried that and it did not work either :/

Comment: Make sure that this question isn't duplicating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794172/c-listbox-remove-part-of-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do simple string manipulation, copy the ListBox's Item collection to a temporary string array, do some work on the array, and copy it back using the Items' Clear() and AddRange() methods. I like using lambda expressions for this kind of manipulation.

**Sort**

```
// Create a regular expression to identify the last column after the whitespace
Regex pattern = new Regex("\\s+\\S+$");

// Dimension an array large enough
string[] items = new string[lbContent.Items.Count];

// Copy the items
lbContent.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

// Use an orderby to sort and convert resulting IEnumerable<> back to array
items = (from i in items
         let m = pattern.Match(i).Value
         orderby m.Trim()
         select i).ToArray();

// Place it back in the collection
lbContent.Items.Clear();
lbContent.Items.AddRange(items);
```

**Trim**

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\\s+\\S+$");
string[] items = new string[lbContent.Items.Count];
lbContent.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

// Replace the last column with empty strings
items = (from i in items
         let m = pattern.Match(i).Value
         select i.Replace(m, string.Empty)).ToArray();

lbContent.Items.Clear();
lbContent.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Or if you're feeling bold...

**Both Simultaneously**

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\\s+\\S+$");
string[] items = new string[lbContent.Items.Count];
lbContent.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

items = (from i in items
         let m = pattern.Match(i).Value
         orderby m.Trim()
         select i.Replace(m, string.Empty)).ToArray();

lbContent.Items.Clear();
lbContent.Items.AddRange(items);
```

**==EDIT==**

**Both Simultaneously, Trimming the strings**

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\\s+\\S+$");
string[] items = new string[lbContent.Items.Count];
lbContent.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

items = (from i in items
         let t = i.Trim(),
         m = pattern.Match(t).Value
         orderby m
         select t.Replace(m, string.Empty)).ToArray();

lbContent.Items.Clear();
lbContent.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: I tried being bold and got the error **String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue**.. I tried to switch the `string.Empty` to `" "` and it also says the same thing. :-/

Comment: That means you have empty strings in the collection more than likely. You cannot perform a replacement operation on an empty string. There's nothing TO replace.

Comment: I think there is an empty string. Is there another way to go about this or to ignore empty strings?

Comment: Sure. Check the edit. All you do is add a "where" condition to the lambda to toss out empty strings.

Comment: I tried that and it still comes up with the same error...hmm?

Comment: Pardon, that was my mistake. It means that m is empty, which is the regular expression match. That means that you have some string in the collection that doesn't meet the criteria of having a final block of non-whitespace characters separated from the rest of the string by preceding whitespace. Do any of your items in the collection not conform to the format given?

Comment: This also prompts me to ask: are the columns in these strings simply tab- or space-separated or have you generated each line as a group of columns for the list box? If this is a multi-column list box then my assumptions based on your calling these "strings" was incorrect and the code would not apply.

Comment: @Ithibodeaux: Actually, I think they are tabs?

Comment: I have an idea... probably trailing whitespace causing the match to fail. Let's trim the collection and see what happens. Check the edit momentarily.